# Nullpointerexception when get button background in android testcase

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-testing

In my app, I want to test button background is correct with what I expect. But I get Nullpointerexception error when try to get button background. I can not see where I wrong.
My code below:

```
    Button btnGetStarted = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnGetStarted);
    Drawable actual = btnGetStarted.getBackground();
    Drawable expect = getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_active_normal);
    assertTrue("Wrong button background", actual==expect);
```

Nullpointerexception at line `Drawable actual = btnGetStarted.getBackground();

I can not solve it after 2 days so I post it on here to looking for help.

Edit:

In xml file I set button background from a picture `btn_getstarted.png` like this: `android:background="@drawable/btn_getstarted"`

Comment: post your onCreate and xml you are using

Comment: Are you sure that btnGetStarted is not null here ?

Comment: I think `onCreate` code have no problem, just `findViewById` and `setOnClickListener` only

Comment: Post the XML layout file

Comment: Yes, I'm sure the button is not null here.

Comment: @user3422401 Did you test the button using assertNotNull in your test code?

Comment: @ZuseeWeekin When I test with robitum assertNotNull(solo.searchButton("Get Started")) it run. But if I change to assertNotNull(getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnGetStarted)) it show me that the testcase fail.

Comment: yes I think so. That's why you are not getting the drawable object here. Try the way I suggest in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your button is null here. That's why you are not getting the drawable. 
Change the code in your test case like this and try :

```
private View inflaterView;
LayoutInflater i=(LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflaterView=i.inflate(R.layout.you_layout_file, null);
        Button btnGetStarted=(Button) inflaterView.findViewById(R.id.btnGetStarted);
```

Addition to this I think comparing two drawable like this is not the correct way. 
If both variables contain references to objects that 'look' the same, they are two different objects instances.So two drawable objects, will not return true on equals.

**As a suggestion to test two drawable objects** get the constantState associated to that Drawables.

```
btnGetStarted.getBackground().getConstantState.getConstantState().equals
            (getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_getstarted).getConstantState())
```

Comment: I tried your code and it run well. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Check, that you button id in xml is "@+id/btnGetStarted". Try to inflate your layout by LayoutInflater and find your button with View.findViewById()